NTFS Disk Only Mounts When Excluded From FSTAB
I'm on Jammy.
I have a new external 6TB disk that I need to share between Windows and Ubuntu for games, but for some reason, it's seemingly impossible to mount, using fstab at least. When allowed to mount automatically, it seems to work, but it's not in the location I want it. When trying to mount using fstab, however, it seems to have some kind of problem with the filesystem.
If filesystem is set to auto, cat /proc/mounts says the filesystem type is fuseblk, which is the same as my other NTFS disks have always shown, but in this case, trying to access it says 'This location is not a folder.' Setting the filesystem to ntfs-3g results in the same. Setting it to ntfs3 mounts it, but of course I don't have access permission to anything on the drive.
When removed from fstab and allowed to mount using defaults, the filesystem is displayed as ntfs3, but for some reason, I have full access to the disk.
EDIT: More information I was asked for:
This is a desktop.
This is the base fstab entry. Everything is totally off the shelf basic, save for the options I added to no change or type entry I changed as detailed above.
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Seagate_Expansion_HDD_00000000NT17G2ZN-0:0-part2 /mnt/Expansion auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

In syslogs, I just found these messages:

It is recommened to use chkdsk.

I've done that with the /r flag from within my Window environment. Took over seven hours and returned no problems. Crystal Disk Info shows no problems as well. GSmartControl doesn't read S.M.A.R.T. info from the majority of the disks I've had (which I know support it), so that's no help.


volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!

I ran ntfsfix on the volume to no change. I also have made sure to turn off fast startup in Windows specifically to prevent this. Like I said, I have no such issues with my other disks, including my Windows system partition.



So... none of that seems to make sense. I also tried the force option to no change, save for both of those messages no longer appearing in logs.

Just to be extra sure this isn't windows fault, can you try ejecting the disks before shutting down windows?

what if you were to mount the disk using the UUID and a mountpoint in ~/media? Something like UUID=[value uuid] /media/[share_name] ntfs defaults 0 0 you can find the UUID using Disks. Also refer to a possible dupe

If you look at the man page for ntfsfix, it says this "ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk." It sets flag so Windows will run chkdsk. Issue often is Windows fast startup which sets hibernation flag. Note that Windows turns fast startup back on with updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

user10489 & graham, I'll give those suggestions and attempt if I'm still facing the issue after rebuilding the partition, which in doing now.

graham, I don't see how that could be a dupe. It's describing different symptoms on a different, now deprecated driver.

oldfred, I'm aware of what ntfsfix does. As I mentioned in the edit above, I ran chkdsk on Windows. I also placed the bullet about using ntfsfix under the one about the 'volume is dirty' message because that's what I used ntfsfix in response to. I've also verified that fast startup is still off, and have tested taking other disks between systems.

I don't see how that could be a dupe I didn't mark it as such - I should really have just suggested it as being related.

I'm assuming you did not add uid= and gid= to your fstab line and specify the ID of your user.  Because that's necessary to mount the NTFS as your user via /etc/fstab mounting.  Note that ntfs and ntfs3 are synonyms, and ntfs-3g is not the proper way to mount NTFS disks.  You should also make sure that wherever you're mounting is, in fact, a directory first (so if you use /data as a mount point, it first has to exist as a directory on system).

Do not see filesystem type  is declared in fstab.
